# Как подключить класс PHP Fine Diff?

Tags: php

Как правильно подключить класс PHP Fine Diff на странице php чтобы работала подсветка разницы в двух строках ?

Comment: На странице по ссылке есть Typical usage:
include 'finediff.php';
$opcodes = FineDiff::getDiffOpcodes($from_text, $to_text /* , default granularity is set to character */);
// store opcodes for later use...  В каком смысле "Разница двух массивов с текстом"? Может просто строки?

Comment: Япробовал но не получается, может я делаю что-то не так

Comment: да, все может быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос на одном итальянском сайте.

```
$opcodes = FineDiff::getDiffOpcodes($from_text, $to_text);
$to_rez = FineDiff::renderDiffToHTMLFromOpcode($from_text, $opcodes);
```

Comment: Ну и написал бы этот ответ.